# What does the @[] symbol represent in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning objective-c, Interviewer asked me this question

What's does the `@[]` symbol mean in objective-c?

Comment: It's an empty array

Comment: it means allocated the empty array

Comment: Why -3, What is wrong with this question ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a `NSArray` class literal. You can create instance using this

```
NSArray *array = @[];
```

the diff way to do this

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

The result the same

Answer (score 2):

It is an empty array since you can create your array like this:

```
NSArray* array = @[@"A", @"B"];
```